# Getting error: "RequestInit: duplex option is required when sending a body" when using dropbox javascript sdk method filesUpload()

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express, dropbox-api

I am trying to implement dropbox api on a songwriting app in React.

I am able to send user to verification and get auth token, and even redirect user back to the proper page, but I can't save the link in the database, or finish uploading the file to dropbox.

I've narrowed the problem down to this block of code in my server:

```
const dropboxResponse = await dbx.filesUpload({
    path: `/uploads/songs/${uploadedSong.originalname}`,
    contents: songFileStream
  });
```

Here is the full error code I get when I submit a new song to upload:

```
Error submitting new song in Database TypeError: RequestInit: duplex option is required when sending a body.
    at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11457:11)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async file:///Users/leedyer/Desktop/Coding/WABS/Server/server.js:232:27
```

And here's the github link:

https://github.com/leerobertdyer/wabs

I've tried adding "duplex: true" in the filesUpload under contents, but it didn't work.

Here is a link to filesUpload in the javascript SDK(code line 1308):
https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-upload

Thank you! Will update if I find a solution...

Answer (score 1):

The error was occurring because my client side code was trying to use a token that hadn't come through yet. I needed to include async language...

This involved:

- Making sure the REDIRECT_URI was the same in both my /auth route and my /auth-callback route
- Storing a temporary version of the token in my server,
- Redirecting back to the homepage with a query parameter holding the temporary token.
- Make sure to delete the temp token after redirecting...
- Then I used a timeout function and urlSearchParams to check for the token.

I understand why this took days to figure out now lol...

If anyone stumbles across this question and needs clarification i'd be happy to try to walk through it with you and get some more experience with this.